# What is the correct way of grabbing an inner string in regular expressions for Python for multiple conditions

Tags: python, regex

I would like to return all strings within the specified starting and end strings.

Given a string `libs = 'libr(lib1), libr(lib2), libr(lib3), req(reqlib), libra(nonlib)'`.

From the above `libs` string I would like to search for strings that are in between `libr(` and `)` or the string between `req(` and `)`.

I would like to return `['lib1', 'lib2', 'lib3', 'reqlib']`

```
import re 
libs = 'libr(lib1), libr(lib2), libr(lib3), req(reqlib), libra(nonlib)'
pat1 = r'libr+\((.*?)\)'
pat2 = r'req+\((.*?)\)'
pat = f"{pat1}|{pat2}"
re.findall(pat, libs)
```

The code above currently returns `[('lib1', ''), ('lib2', ''), ('lib3', ''), ('', 'reqlib')]` and I am not sure how I should fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex

```
(?:(?<=libr\()|(?<=req\())[^)]+
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dx8a4Z/1)**

**[Click for Code](https://regex101.com/r/dx8a4Z/1/codegen?language=python)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?:(?<=libr\()|(?<=req\())`

  - `(?<=libr\()` - positive lookbehind that matches the position which is immediately preceded by text `libr(`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<=req\()` - positive lookbehind that matches the position which is immediately preceded by text `req(`
- `[^)]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character which is not a `)`. So, this will match everything until it finds the next `)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
pat1 = r'(?<=libr\().*?(?=\))'
pat2 = r'(?<=req\().*?(?=\))'
```

It uses positive lookbehind `(?<=)` and positive lookahead `(?=)`.

- `.*?` : selects all characters in between. I'll name it "content"
- `(?<=libr\()` : "content" must be preceded by `libr(` (we escape the
  `(` )
- `?(?=\))` : content must be followed by `)` ( `(` is escaped too)

Complete code:

```
import re 
libs = 'libr(lib1), libr(lib2), libr(lib3), req(reqlib), libra(nonlib)'
pat1 = r'(?<=libr\().*?(?=\))'
pat2 = r'(?<=req\().*?(?=\))'
pat = f"{pat1}|{pat2}"
result = re.findall(pat, libs)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['lib1', 'lib2', 'lib3', 'reqlib']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a common way to do so is using alternation in the word you would want to be preceding the pattern you like to capture:

```
\b(?:libr|req)\(([^)]+)
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/a6ELwn/1)

- `\b` - Word-boundary.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `libr|req` - Match "libr" **or** "req".
  - `)` - Close non-capture group.
- `\(` - A literal opening paranthesis.
- `(` - Open a capture group:

  - `[^)]+` - Match 1+ characters apart from closing paranthesis.
  - `)` - Close capture group.

---

A python demo:

```
import re
libs = 'libr(lib1), libr(lib2), libr(lib3), req(reqlib), libra(nonlib)'
lst = re.findall(r'\b(?:libr|req)\(([^)]+)', libs)
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['lib1', 'lib2', 'lib3', 'reqlib']
```